# File Upload with Relay and graphql-dotnet

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, graphql, relayjs, graphql-dotnet

I'm trying to build a mutation within relay that includes a file. As soon as I implement the `getFiles()` method referenced here: https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/api-reference-relay-mutation.html#getfiles

Relay sends a multipart request causing a 415 error from ASP.NET Core MVC.

I'm looking for a working example, similar to "[How would you do file uploads in a React-Relay app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33060182/how-would-you-do-file-uploads-in-a-react-relay-app)" with the [graphql-dotnet library](https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/graphql-dotnet).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The GraphQL Endpoint wasn't accepting the multi-part form mimetype because it wasn't JSON. I was able to work with the files once I got them into graphql-dotnet via the RootObject and the context that's available in the mutation. What was throwing me off was MVC.

So I wrote a simple Filter:

```
public class RelayResourceFilter : IResourceFilter
{
    private readonly string jsonMediaType = "application/json";

    public void OnResourceExecuted(ResourceExecutedContext context)
    {
    }

    public void OnResourceExecuting(ResourceExecutingContext context)
    {


        if (!string.Equals(MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse(context.HttpContext.Request.ContentType).MediaType,
            this.jsonMediaType, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            var encoder = JavaScriptEncoder.Create();
            var variables = encoder.Encode(context.HttpContext.Request.Form["variables"]);
            var query = encoder.Encode(context.HttpContext.Request.Form["query"]);
            var body = $"{{\"query\":\"{query}\", \"variables\":\"{variables}\"}}";

            byte[] requestData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body);
            context.HttpContext.Request.Body = new MemoryStream(requestData);
            context.HttpContext.Request.ContentType = this.jsonMediaType;
        }
    }
}
```

registered it:

```
services.AddScoped<RelayResourceFilter>();
```

and then applied it like so in the Controller:

```
[ServiceFilter(typeof(RelayResourceFilter))]
    public async Task<ExecutionResult> Post([FromBody]GraphQLQuery query, bool? useErrorCode)
{
var files = this.Request.HasFormContentType ? this.Request.Form.Files : null;
// ... assignment to Root Object
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you just having trouble figuring out how to access the files in your resolver on the server?  You can pass the files as your `rootObject` or `userContext`.

```
// GraphQLController
var files = Request.Form.Files;
var userContext = files;

var result = await executer.ExecuteAsync(
    schema,
    rootObject,
    query,
    operationName,
    inputs,
    userContext).ConfigureAwait(false);

// Mutation type
Field<StringGraphType>(
  "uploadFile",
  arguments: new QueryArguments(new QueryArgument<NonNullGraphType<StringGraphType>> {Name = "fileName"}),
  resolve: context =>
  {
      var userContext = context.UserContext.As<IFormFileCollection>();

      // process files

      // return data
      return "success";
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Joe. I actually ended up writing a small ResourceFilter for the GraphQL endpoint:

Comment: How I can read query from his? In general I am reading like this `var request = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GraphQLQueryModel>(body);`. Then `request` is object which contains query. If I am uploading file content is not `application/json`.

Comment: @kat1330  I would look at the accepted answer.  You need to check the media type.  See also https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/relay/blob/master/src/GraphQL.Relay/Http/Deserializer.cs

Comment: @JoeMcBride Thanks. I prefer to use is middleware. Do you know which type is most suitable for mutation `QueryArgument` for file upload?

Comment: @kat1330 I'm not sure I fully understand your question (perhaps add an issue on the GraphQL .NET project with more info?) - but I think you're asking how you pass files as Query Arguments.  Short answer is you can't.  You'll have to access them via the User Context.